# Is there any way to specify a default function to use when formatting specific columns in the mysql client?

Tags: mysql, uuid

While developing my app, I frequently use the `mysql` command line client to inspect and modify the DB. I'm using UUIDs for my keys, with type `varbinary(16)`. This is nicely formatted using `bin_to_uuid()`, but it's cumbersome to write that explicitly every time I query the DB.

Is there any way to tell the client to always run the value through a function for specific columns, so I can write something like `select * from Users;` and get the `id` column formatted as a UUID instead of garbage?

Comment: Would creating a view work here?

Comment: I imagine you could make it work by creating something like information_schema.columns and using dynamic sql but that's a lot more cumbersome than what you have to do now.

Comment: It's not more cumbersome if I can do it once and then not worry about it again.

Comment: @Progman Yes! The view seems like it gets me 80% of the way there. I have to re-create it each time my schema changes, which is often right now, but it at least makes it easy to `select * from`. Thanks!